# Python function error : '<' not supported between types 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, function, operators

I am working on repeats classification project. I am calculating time lapse in between a repeat and fresh mail in days. I want to apply a function on this time lapse which states whether it is a fresh mail or repeat mail.

function:

```
days = df['days_difference']
if(days<30):
   return 'repeat'
else:
   return 'fresh'
```

I am getting error: not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

'days_difference' column contains integer values along with None values.

looking for a solution !

Comment: The error is telling you the issue: `df['days_difference']` is of type `str`

Comment: Also, is this really a dataframe? I would expect a different error: is it actually a dictionary? If it's just a regular python dictionary then you should avoid the name `df` because it will cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: Use `print(type(df['days_difference']))` and see if it is really an integer (hint: it is not).

Answer (score 1):

That basically means that your 'days ' variable is a string. You can not compare strings with integers using "<".
Try :

```
...
if(int(days)<30):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explaining :

> Python function error : '<' not supported between types 'str' and 'int'

This is caused by a comparison of `str` and `int` types, which is invalid in Python 3 (although it's ok in Python 2).

Example :

```
result = '20' > 10  # In Python 3, this is illegal and will raise an exception
```

In your case, the error is most probably caused by the test `if(days<30):`. Your dataframe probably contains `str` values. You may need to convert them to `int` before trying to compare to another value:

```
days = int(df['days_difference'])
if(days<30):
   return 'repeat'
else:
   return 'fresh'
```

Comment: Although it is coming to an end, such comparisons are possible in Python 2

Comment: Thanks @roganjosh, I didn't know this comparison was valid in 2.x. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Valid, but nonsensical nonetheless, hence its removal :)

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation which you should consider, always perform a search with the exact error you get from python, and often times you get your response within 0.1 ms.

In your case, you are comparing an integer value (let's say 2) to a string value, which happens to be '2') and python does not understand.

You can compare `int(days)' and 30 like:

```
if(int(day) < 30):
    return 'repeat'
else: 
    return 'fresh'
```