# How do I resolve TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, sys

I am trying to use the following code to train Keras-I3D model from the following link:

https://github.com/srijandas07/i3d. I have slightly modified the code, but I can get it work.

imported modules are

```
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'tensorflow'

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="3" 

from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Reshape
from keras import regularizers
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from i3d_inception import Inception_Inflated3d, conv3d_bn
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint, CSVLogger, Callback
from keras.utils import Sequence, multi_gpu_model

import random
import sys
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import numpy as np
import glob
from skimage.io import imread
import cv2
```

some definitions

```
epochs = sys.argv[0]
#epochs = 17
model_name = sys.argv[0]
#model_name = model_name
version = sys.argv[0]
num_classes = 35
batch_size = 16
stack_size = 64
DataLoader_video_train = DataLoader_video_train
DataLoader_video_test = DataLoader_video_test
```

```
class CustomModelCheckpoint(Callback):

    def __init__(self, model_parallel, path):

        super(CustomModelCheckpoint, self).__init__()

        self.save_model = model_parallel
        self.path = path
        self.nb_epoch = 0

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        self.nb_epoch += 1
        self.save_model.save(self.path + str(self.nb_epoch) + '.hdf5')


i3d = i3d_modified(weights = 'rgb_imagenet_and_kinetics')
model = i3d.i3d_flattened(num_classes = num_classes)
optim = SGD(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor = 0.1, patience = 10)
csvlogger = CSVLogger('i3d_'+model_name+'.csv')
```

```
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = optim, metrics = ['accuracy'])

model_checkpoint = CustomModelCheckpoint(model, './weights_'+model_name+'/epoch_')    

train_generator = DataLoader_video_train('/train_CS.txt',version, batch_size = batch_size)
test_generator = DataLoader_video_test('/test_CS.txt', version, batch_size = batch_size)
```

fit generator

```
model.fit_generator(
    generator = train_generator,
    #validation_data=val_generator,
    epochs = epochs, 
    steps_per_epoch = 17, 
    callbacks = [csvlogger, reduce_lr, model_checkpoint], 
    max_queue_size = 48,
    workers = cpu_count() - 2,
    use_multiprocessing = True,
)

print(model.evaluate_generator(generator = test_generator))
```

I get the following error

```
runfile('D:/Clones/i3d-master/i3d_train.py', wdir='D:/Clones/i3d-master')
Reloaded modules: i3d_inception
C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py:47: UserWarning: Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True` and multiple workers may duplicate your data. Please consider using the`keras.utils.Sequence class.
  UserWarning('Using a generator with `use_multiprocessing=True`'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-8f7b9cc152d8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Clones/i3d-master/i3d_train.py', wdir='D:/Clones/i3d-master')

  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Clones/i3d-master/i3d_train.py", line 108, in <module>
    use_multiprocessing = True,

  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1418, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "C:\Users\sancy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 174, in fit_generator
    while epoch < epochs:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

What am I doing wrong? What does `epoch < epochs` mean?

Windows 10
python 3.7.1
spyder: 3.7

Comment: Maybe try: ```epochs = int(sys.argv[0])``` it's probably assigned as ```str``` type otherwise, which doesn't work in your further code.

Comment: got this error when I did that. ```epochs = int(sys.argv[0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'D:/Clones/i3d-master/i3d_train.py'```

Comment: you should use `sys.argv[1]` instead of `sys.argv[0]` because in `sys.argv[0]` is always script name. And if you have more optons then you will need `[2]`, `[3]`, etc. See `print( sys.argv )` and `print( len(sys.argv) )`. But it may be safer to use module `argparse` for this.

Comment: Thanks! I get this `File "D:/Clones/i3d-master/i3d_train.py", line 27, in <module>
    epochs = sys.argv[1]

IndexError: list index out of range` when I use `sys.argv[1]`. I will try using `argparse`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python function error : '<' not supported between types 'str' and 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669611/python-function-error-not-supported-between-types-str-and-int)

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the code? Looking at the Github repo, it takes 3 arguments

[i3d_train.py](https://github.com/srijandas07/i3d/blob/969b4e9431184a7cc8c203f50ad3a8b728fcaec6/i3d_train.py#L24)

```
epochs = int(sys.argv[1])
model_name = sys.argv[2]
version = sys.argv[3]
```

[finetune.sh](https://github.com/srijandas07/i3d/blob/master/finetune.sh)

```
export PATH=/home/sdas/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
module load cuda/8.0 cudnn/5.1-cuda-8.0 opencv/3.4.1
mkdir -p weights_$2
python ./i3d_train.py $1 $2 $3
```

On a terminal, you should run it like this

`python ./i3d_train.py <epochs> <model_name> <version>`

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen because of compatibility issues as quoted in the link below.

You should use `learning_rate` instead of `lr` while initializing the optimizer. This solved my error.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L362-L363